# Struts Validation Framework: Validation Summary is blank

Tags: java, validation, struts, struts-validation

**BACKGROUND**

I am learning Struts 1.x and currently on the validation framework.

**PROBLEM**

I have it in a semi-working condition. Currently it is showing the validation errors, but in a javascript alert.. and then the validation summary (the thing generated by `<html:error>`) is blank.. well, it has 3 bullet points where the validation errors are supposed to be, but no text.

1. I would not have expected it to use a javascript alert. I only want the validation summary. How can I turn this off, if possible?
2. Why is the validation summary missing text?

**EDIT**

Here is some of the code, if it helps.

struts-config.xml

```
<form-beans>
        <form-bean name="ProductActionForm" type="actionForms.ProductActionForm"/>
    </form-beans>
```

validation.xml

```
<form name="ProductActionForm">
            <field property="name" depends="required">
                <arg key="ProductActionForm.name"/>
            </field>
            <field property="price" depends="required,float">
                <arg key="ProductActionForm.price"/>
            </field>
            <field property="quantityInStock" depends="integer,intRange">
                <arg0 key="ProductActionForm.quantityInStock"/>
                <arg1 name="intRange" key="${var:min}" resource="false"/>
                <arg2 name="intRange" key="${var:max}" resource="false"/>
                <var>
                    <var-name>min</var-name>
                    <var-value>0</var-value>
                </var>
                <var>
                    <var-name>max</var-name>
                    <var-value>9999</var-value>
                </var>
            </field>
        </form>
```

JSP HTML:

```
<html:javascript formName="ProductActionForm" />
        <html:errors></html:errors>
        <html:form action="/AddProductAction" method="post" onsubmit="validateProductActionForm(this);">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name: </td>
                        <td><html:text property="name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Price: </td>
                        <td><html:text property="price" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td># In Stock </td>
                        <td><html:text property="quantityInStock" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </html:form>
```

**EDIT 2**

Here are some screenshots:

Showing javascript alert:
[image: Showing javascript alert]

Showing blank validation summary:
[image: Showing blank validation summary]

Comment: Please give some codes from xml and action where you are getting problem. or add website example from wher you got code and check yourself also.

Comment: @sunleo, please see my edit. If anything else is needed, just let me know. Thanks.

Comment: sorry Matt I couldn't correct your entire code. it will take time and space so I gave an answer check my answer below.I got answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Matt Here we go There are 2 types of Struts1 Validations

**1. Validate using ActionErrors validate in Bean itself(show summary)**

**2. Validate using xml and configure everything here itself.(javascript alert)**

for your case you used second type that is correct,But to get summary alone check this link thats all, if you  get problem in link or its example , Please ping me.

[This is the example](http://www.rameshsengani.in/vaannila/struts/struts-example/struts-highlighting-error-fields-example-1.html)

Comment: Thank you. The problem was my error message were missing from the ApplicationResource.properties file. I did not think to check for that because the error messages were being displayed just fine in the JS alert box and I assumed the validation summary would be getting its messages from the same place.

Comment: Also, thanks for letting me know that it is 2 separate validation mechanisms.. I had assumed there was only 1.. this sure helped.